# money-rails - rounding up method

Tags: ruby, money-rails

I have this method below:

```
  def formatted_from_net_per_day
    return unless object.price.available?
    formatted_price_for(object.price.from_price)
  end
```

As an example, it outputs:

```
#<Money fractional:78571 currency:GBP>
```

The `formatted_price_for` method is as below where it strips away the cents.

```
  def formatted_price_for(price)
    formatted_price = h.money_without_cents_and_with_symbol(price)
    unit = I18n.t("space.pricings.pricing.day")

    format('%s/%s', formatted_price, unit)
  end
```

Instead of stripping the cents away, I want to round up the money and retain the currency. So using the example output above - `£785.71 -> £786`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just [reading the README](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#configuration-parameters) and checking [the source code](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/c8c1dc8501f6c33e3f104289e722570d8b747bde/lib/money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension.rb#L33-L50)... Does this work? `h.money_without_cents(price, symbol: true, rounding_mode: BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING)`

Comment: That didn't work -  it gave me £785

Comment: Also tried - `h.humanized_money(space.price.from_price, symbol: true, rounding_mode: BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING)` but gave me £785.71

Comment: This is ugly, but what about `Money.with_rounding_mode(BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING) { h.money_with_cents_and_with_symbol(price) }`? ([link](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/8754d9ae614b8903525746589a6fed104d469344/lib/money/money.rb#L234-L239))

Comment: I got  - undefined method `with_rounding_mode' for Money:Class

Comment: `Money.with_rounding_mode` was [added to version `6.13.3`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#6133) of the `money` gem. Unless you say otherwise, I'm going to assume you're using the latest version of the gem. In older versions, it seems the method was called `Money.with_rounding_mode`.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work either. Still giving me £785

Comment: *`Money.rounding_mode`. (Shame SO doesn't let me edit comments :( ... )